# React hooks inside a curry function (creating a HOC) returning an error from linter 'React Hook "useContext" cannot be called inside a callback'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, currying, high-order-component, react-hoc

In my project, I got rid of classes and I'm just using Hooks. Now that I'm trying to create a HOC, my linter is returning an error for using Hooks inside my curry function. This is the simplified version of my code:

```js
const myCurryFunction = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState();
  return <WrappedComponent {...props} />
}
```

And the full eslint error is this one:

```
React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.
```

Any clue? I'll really appreciate any advice

Comment: Hooks must be called on the top level of our components https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: Following that, I tend to think that we cannot use hooks with this HOC pattern :/

Comment: Can it be done with a custom hook?

Comment: What do you mean @JosephD.? To move all my logic into a custom hook and then using this inside my curry function? If yes, I don't think so. If hooks are complaining because they have to be at the top is because otherwise can bring bugs for the order on how are executed.

Answer (score 1):

Two choices for you.

1. [Respect the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), make changes to your code.

   const myCurryFunction = WrappedComponent =>
     function Comp(props) {
      const [state, setState] = React.useState();
      return 
     }
2. Turn off the lint for the source file.

Answer (score 1):

I found this github issue:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20531

The HOC pattern should work, but is very specific.